Optional<User> findByEmail(String email) not working
I'm updating my Spring Boot 2.5.x project to Spring Boot 3.3.3.
I've used a method called findByEmail which was working fine with the 2.5 version.
The repository is the following:
@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false)
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<User> {
Stream<UserDashboardSearchProjection> findByEmailIsNotNull();
    Optional<User> findById(Long userId);
    Optional<User> findByEmail(String email);
}

After the update the findByEmail always return an Optional.empty even the email is exists in the database. If I list all of the users with a findAll() method all of the emails will be in the list.
These are the dependencies of the project:
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <version>8.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>32.0.0-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.30</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
            <version>0.13</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.28.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
            <artifactId>flying-saucer-pdf</artifactId>
            <version>9.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.core5</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client-gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client-jackson2</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.stripe</groupId>
            <artifactId>stripe-java</artifactId>
            <version>20.40.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

The User class is the following:
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class User extends AbstractAuditable<Long> {

    @Convert(converter = StringEncryptor.class)
    private String password;

    @Email
    @Convert(converter = QueryableStringEncryptor.class)
    private String email;

    @Email
    @Convert(converter = QueryableStringEncryptor.class)
    private String facebookEmail;
    @Convert(converter = QueryableStringEncryptor.class)
    private String googleEmail;
    @Convert(converter = StringEncryptor.class)
    private String googleUserId;
    @Convert(converter = QueryableStringEncryptor.class)
    private String linkedInId;

    @Convert(converter = StringEncryptor.class)
    private String firstName;

    @Convert(converter = StringEncryptor.class)
    private String lastName;

    @Convert(converter = StringEncryptor.class)
    private String birthName;

    @Convert(converter = StringEncryptor.class)
    private String phone;

    private String country;
    private String birthCountry;
    private String nationality;
    private String taxResidenceCountry;
    private String stateProvince;
    private String zip;
    private String city;
    private String street;

    private boolean enabled;

    @Convert(converter = StringEncryptor.class)
    @Column(length = 10000)
    private String biography;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Currency currency = Currency.HUF;

    private String facebook;
    private String twitter;
    private String linkedIn;
    private String website;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate quizCompletionDate;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDateTime lastLoginDate;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Set<Role> roles;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Set<Category> categories;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Set<NewsLetter> newsLetterList;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<AuthToken> authTokens;

    private String locale;
    private String applicantId;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private SocialPlatform registeredWith = SocialPlatform.EMAIL;
    private boolean connectedFacebook;
    private boolean connectedLinkedIn;

    @Convert(converter = StringEncryptor.class)
    private String mothersMaidenName;
    @Convert(converter = StringEncryptor.class)
    private String birthplace;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate birthDate;
    @Convert(converter = StringEncryptor.class)
    private String identificationDocumentNumber;
    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    private FileType identificationDocumentType;
    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    private FileType identificationDocumentTypeBack;
    private LocalDate investorDocumentApprovalDate;
    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    private IdentificationStatus identificationStatus;
    private String sumSubLang;
    private Boolean hasProjectAccepted = Boolean.FALSE;
    @Transient
    private String profilePictureUrl;
    @Transient
    private String fullName;
    private String mentorLink;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<MentorTag> mentorTag;
    private String vatNumber;
    private String gender;
    @Convert(converter = StringEncryptor.class)
    private String nutshellId;
    private LocalDateTime disabledDate;
    private LocalDateTime deletedDate;
    private boolean isDisabled = false;
    private boolean isDeleted = false;
    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    private TwoFactorAuthType twoFactorAuthType=TwoFactorAuthType.TWO_FACTOR_DISABLED;
    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    private DeletedBy deletedBy;
    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    private DisabledBy disabledBy;
    private String mfaSecret;
}

Do you have any idea what could be the issue here? How could I make this work?

Please post also the User source code; have you tried to activate the show_sql option in the properties, and check the query that is generated?

Please add the source code for the service that calls findByEmail.

Maybe the problem is related to the encryption of the field, and if (and how / when) the email parameter value is encrypted before is binded into the query? Is it possible to show also what the QueryableStringEncryptor does?
